# How can I add another row to the total field in WooCoommerce cart, checkout and recipe mail?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched a lot to find out how I can add a custom row inside the total costs in my WooCommerce shop and checked out the hooks but can't find the solution. This is what I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email( $total_rows, $myorder_obj ) {

$total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
    'label' => __( 'Rec:', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => 'blabla'
);

return $total_rows;
}
```

But this only adds the row to the total rows in the recipe email. I need to change my total row, add a new row with a name and a value calculated from the cart subtotal field.

This is how I need it:

[image]

Do you now how to to this? I have no plan. Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**
I don't want to change the original php file. I know this might be the simplest solution but I don't want to make changes in the WooCommerce system because of updates and all the other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

if you take a look at the source code of `cart-total.php`  and the checkout `review-order.php` you will find there is hook `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping`  which enable you to add the row in the position  you want but you should have the shipping is active as this action will not be executed  unless `WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping()` is true .

so for example you can do the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'add_row' , 99);
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'add_row' , 99);
function add_row() {
    ?>
        <tr> 
            <th>test</th>
        <td>test td</td>
</tr>

    <?php
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

but if the user add a coupon the discount amount row will be added before your new row. and if that not acceptable to you then you have no choice but to modify the both template `cart-total.php`  and  `review-order.php`  which is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've tried to add this to my functions.php but no effect.

Comment: @Johnny97 i added priority to those hooks try them now

Comment: I've already tried that with prio 1000 but no effect lol but its working on your side.

Comment: @Johnny97 it might your theme modifying those template as for example the Subtotal in your theme is Cart Total so take a look at your theme template